# nested c++ for loop parallelized with openmp

Tags: c++, openmp, nested-loops

I would like to set the diagonals of a matrix using openmp.

this a part of the plan:

```
for(int i=0; i<II; i++)
{
//calculate JJ
#pragma omp parallel for private(j)
  for(j=0; j<JJ; j++)
  {
    for(k=0; k<JJ; k++)
     {
       for(l=0; l<JJ; l++)
        {
          //calculate A
           for(m=0; m<JJ; m++)
           {
            if(j==l && k==m)
           {
            //calculate B
            // calculate c=A-B
       add C to matrix(diagonal, diagonal);
           }
         }
        }
diagonal++;
   }
  }
}
```

How can you parallelise this with openmp? Would it be possible to parallelise only the inner loops? when I run this it gives me the wrong result.

Thanks

Comment: Why have you 5 nested loops, when 3 would do? You don't need l and m as your loop body will only use them, when they are equal to j and k

Answer (score 2):

You have a loop-carried dependency given by the:

```
diagonal++;
```

statement. Therefore you can't parallelize this with OpenMP. You need to find a way to break that dependency (maybe running that statement within an `#pragma omp ordered` directive)

Comment: thanks for the prompt reply. I see what the problem is. I am going to try to rewrite the loop as @MikeMB suggested. I could not place the pragma omp ordered without getting the usual error message :. ordered region must be closely nested inside a loop region with an ordered clause

Comment: I have reorganized the loops and ended up having a single for loop and a nesetd for loop with two for loops. The task got much faster by itself on one core but I still need to run it for massive numbers.